# Eclipse and python not resolving imports

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm doing some imports with python and sometimes I do not have that package yet, so I  install the package.

The problem is when I test it in python's interpreter it resolves the imports :

```
    Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from termcolor import colored
>>>
```

However in eclipse I still get errors of unresolved imports, how can I fix this ? 
Are there any other eclipse like editors out there for python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to reconfigure in Pydev the python interpreter to get the new added libs.

From Pydev tutorial:

> If you add something to your python installation, you need to either
>   add it manually as a 'new folder' in the System PYTHONPATH (if it's
>   still not under a folder in the PYTHONPATH) or (recommended) **remove
>   your interpreter and add it again, then, press apply.**
>
> Note that if you added a library that's already under a folder in the
>   PYTHONPATH, you have to at least go to the interpreter preferences and
>   press apply so that it clears its internal caches (after the
>   configuration is done, things are set in stone for PyDev)

Comment: I think it is the same in other similar IDEs as PyCharm